# Angular 5 test fails "Module parse failed"

Tags: unit-testing, pug, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, angular5

I am working on angular 5 application, and I am using pug as a template engine,
the app working fine but when i tried to run testing, i got this error:

```
    ERROR in ./src/app/directives/footer/footer.component.pug         
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:20)                      
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.      
       .col                                                      
         .powerdBy                                      
           span.mr-2 Powered by                                  
           img(src="assets/images/{{imgSource}}")                

    @ ./src/app/directives/footer/footer.component.ts 24:22-55       
    @ ./src/app/directives/footer/footer.component.spec.ts           
    @ ./src \.spec\.ts$                                              
    @ ./src/test.ts
```

it seems to have a problem with compiling pug template

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Comment: What's on line 24 of footer.component.ts?